# Substrings in Zendesk Templates?

Tags: zendesk

I'm working on a really rudimentary forum built in Zendesk and can't find much or any information on how their variables / markup works.  I'd like to display a partial name instead of full name alongside user posts.

Ideally I'd be able to convert this first name last initial.  So "John Smith" would appear as "John S." instead.

Here is the code block that appears all over the forum / community in the help center. Right now I only have access to the code via the help center but there may be a theme export / import that I've yet to find with exposes more of the pseudo Handlebars implementation they have.  I'm working under the assumption that only agents / admins have access to view the author.url but in both instances I need to shorten that username.

```
{{#if author.url}}
<a href="{{author.url}}" target="_zendesk_lotus">
  {{author.name}}
</a>
{{else}}
{{author.name}}
{{/if}}
```

It looks like there are "display names" but those are available only to agents and admins and not individual users (not that we'd want to update our 3k+ users by hand to set a display name).

**tl;dr** the names of users are automatically generated by our software on account create using the full first and last names.  We'd like to change the way that these names display in the forum / community to be First name, Last Initial:

```
David Smith => David S
```

The closest function available I could find to pull this off is the excerpt one but it just truncates a string to a char limit: https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/help-center-templates/helpers#excerpt-helper

I could whip up a solution to do this with client side javascript on page load but I'd much rather not take that route.  Maybe I'll have to create a custom app or something else to get a separate function added tot he theme code?  Any suggestions or help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're asking/what the issue is? Thanks.

Comment: I'm hoping to convert usernames to display as first name / last initial.  Essentially a substring or regex replace to the first "word" in the name if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Where is this code located? Is it from the Help Center, in a Zendesk app, or somewhere else, like an external app that accesses Zendesk data?

Comment: The code I've been working on is through the editor in the help center - I think it's part of a community module made available in a more recent version of Zendesk but it's integrated with the theme itself.  I haven't found a way to export my theme and get access to the underlying "Handlebars-esque" functions they use but if that was an option I'd be all over it.

I've updated my question with an example of what appears vs what I'd like to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but IMO this is not possible; I looked into the following in arriving at my answer

**On the Server - Side**

The Zendesk API entry for the user object which is not atomic when it comes to the name (see https://developer.zendesk.com/apps/docs/help-center-templates/objects#user-object). Also I looked into Zendesk's 'Global Helpers', 'Shared Helpers' and 'Advanced Helpers' (i.e. the 'excerpt' helper you mentioned) and nothing did what we want.

**On the Client - Side**

1. Firstly, whereas JavaScript can be used to guarantee that a full
   second name is indeed truncated to just the first letter for display
   purposes, it **cannot** guarantee that the full second name can be
   secured from prying eyes for privacy purposes. I mention this
   because if you live in a EU country the GDPR regulations kick in on
   or around May 25 2018.
2. Since CSS3 doesn't have a 'first-word' pseudo selector that probably rules out a straightforward approach with CSS. Maybe a bidi-direction and text-indent hack could work but I feel that that the effort involved would be too great given the concerns point 1) raises and if you really have to proceed with a client-side solution JavaScript would be your best bet (see [Targeting specific text entered into form input field and add styles to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757000/targeting-specific-text-entered-into-form-input-field-and-add-styles-to-it))

Comment: Yep, I came to the conclusion long ago that Zendesk's help center is very mediocre in terms of the flexibility that it offers.